# IE no longer renders local HTML files after uninstalling Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, uninstall, html-files

Where I work, I had a user that installed Google Chrome on his Windows 7 SP1 64-bit system under his account (domain environment, he is local administrator) accidentally when installing Google Earth.

The user did not check the "Use Chrome as default" checkbox and thus local `.htm`/`.html` files were by default opening in Chrome. Our ERP software is based on ActiveX and therefore will not work in Chrome. So I uninstalled it.

Now, whenever local `.htm`/`.html` files are opened, IE 8 launches, but instead of rendering the page, the source code of the page is displayed - as though it's not recognizing that it is an `.html` file but a text file.

*Remote* `.htm`/`.html` files open OK, i.e. when IE 8 is opened and an address is typed.  It is *only* when a local `.htm`/`.html` is opened that IE will not recognize it as HTML.

I have since reinstalled Chrome, but did not set it as the default browser. However, the behavior persists.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is there a difference in the address when you open the files locally vs remotely?

Comment: What is the default program set to for .htm or .html files? This can be found in the Default Programs list.

Comment: Does this happen for *every* HTML file? What happens if you make a new **.html** file from scratch that contains: `<html><head><title>Test</title></head><body><p>Hello</p></body></html>` ... ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the registry, go to `Computer\hkey_class_root\.htm` and change the default to `htmlfile` (and not `chrome`).